# sync() and attach() not working together?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my controller first i attach array of ids like this for my additional fields:

```
$property->features()->attach($additional_ids);
```

Then im using `sync()` because i have checkboxes :

```
 $property->features()->sync($features);
```

But problem is when i have this then my `attach()` is not working. Any suggestion how can i fix  this? When i remove this `sync()` my attach is working. So idea is that i have checkboxes for features, and i have input fields for some additional features.I store this ids in pivot table .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sync()` will override all changes made by `attach()`. So, just [merge arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and use `sync()`:

```
$property->features()->sync(array_merge($features, $additional_ids));
```

Comment: it remember this $additional_ids for the first time but when i change something for $features or when i just submit form again they disappear?

Comment: @uzhas `sync()` will delete all relations except those which are in an array you're sending as a parameter. It just doesn't make sense to use `attach()` before `sync()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$property->features()->sync($features, false);
```

Which will [sync without detaching](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_sync).

Or you could also call:

```
$property->features()->syncWithoutDetaching($features)
```

Which will do the same.